# Spring MVC Ajax call POST not working

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form which I convert into an object. I wanna pass that object onto the server, a GET ajax request works fine but the object is empty in the java method, then I do the very same request but a POST request and it says error 404. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or what is, followed many examples, but neither of them seem to work.

GET REQUEST

(Ajax call)

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/pp/portal/" + businessId64 + "/saveMedicalQuestionnaire",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: { medicalHistoryDTO : medicalHistoryDTO },
     success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
     }
});
```

(Object medicalHistoryDTO)

[image: Object]

(Java Method)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/*/saveMedicalQuestionnaire", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String postEditMedical(MedicalHistoryDTO medicalHistoryDTO)
{
    System.out.println("COMMON CONTROLLER POSTEDITMEDICAL SAVE MEDICAL QUESTIONNAIRE");
    System.out.println(medicalHistoryDTO);

    return "WORKING FINE";  
}
```

(Eclipse console)

```
COMMON CONTROLLER POSTEDITMEDICAL SAVE MEDICAL QUESTIONNAIRE
MedicalHistoryDTO [list=null, medicalHistorySignature=null]
```

(Browser console)
[image]

POST REQUEST

(Ajax call)

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/pp/portal/" + businessId64 + "/saveMedicalQuestionnaire",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: { medicalHistoryDTO : medicalHistoryDTO },
     success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
     }
});
```

(Java Method)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/*/saveMedicalQuestionnaire", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String postEditMedical(MedicalHistoryDTO medicalHistoryDTO)
{
    System.out.println("COMMON CONTROLLER POSTEDITMEDICAL SAVE MEDICAL QUESTIONNAIRE");
    System.out.println(medicalHistoryDTO);

    return "WORKING FINE";  
}
```

(Browser console)

[image]

Comment: try to specify path more strictly  `value="/path/saveMedicalQuestionnaire"` instead `value="/*/saveMedicalQuestionnaire"`

Comment: Check https://www.boraji.com/spring-4-mvc-jquery-ajax-form-submit-example, I think the form which you are sending is not in the format which your controller method is expecting

Answer (score 1):

Keep using POST and to recieve you need to use @RequestBody tag

```
public @ResponseBody String postEditMedical(@RequestBody MedicalHistoryDTO medicalHistoryDTO)
```

You can see a working example from my code to https://github.com/shakeelabbas1/webservice/blob/master/src/main/java/com/service/controller/ServiceRequestController.java

Update: 
I also see     `data: { medicalHistoryDTO : medicalHistoryDTO }`
Replace it with `data: medicalHistoryDTO`

Comment: Tried this, still error 404, I'm starting to think that there is something wrong with the server configuration and not the actual ajax calls because the error is 404 "Not Found" and not 403, 405, 401, 400  or any that might suggest what is wrong

Comment: Its strange that same URL is working for GET but not for POST.
Have you tried sending data as asked in update. Also remove contentType, datatype

Comment: You can try `@PostMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping`, I had this issue where my `method = RequestMethod.POST` didn't register for some mysterious reason.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify path more strictly

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/saveMedicalQuestionnair", , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String postEditMedical(MedicalHistoryDTO medicalHistoryDTO, @PathVariable("id") int id)
```

Comment: tried to specify the whole path strictly whit the businessId as PathVariable as well, still error 404.

Comment: do u have anotation with this path _/pp/portal/_ on your controller?